# Retorno busca HQL JAVA

Tags: java, hql

Tenho a seguinte função que busca no BD um usuário que satisfaça o login e senha passados por parâmetro:

```
public Usuario getUsuarioLogin(String pLogin, String pSenha) {       
    String hql = " select u from Usuario u "
               + " where u.login =:pLogin "
               + " and u.senha =:pSenha ";

    Query query = this.getManager().createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("pLogin", pLogin);
    query.setParameter("pSenha", pSenha);       

    return (Usuario) query.getSingleResult();

}
```

Quando passo login e senha que existem no BD tudo bem, porém oque irá retornar caso a busca dê em nada, tentei comparar o valor retornado com null, porém ele não reconheceu a condição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--) a forma feita para indicar a ausência de resultado é o lançamento de uma [NoResultException](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html).

Nesse caso você precisará utilizar um bloco `try-catch` para detectar um retorno sem resultados e prosseguir conforme desejado.

Ex.:

```
public Usuario getUsuarioLogin(String pLogin, String pSenha) {       
    String hql = " select u from Usuario u "
               + " where u.login =:pLogin "
               + " and u.senha =:pSenha ";

    Query query = this.getManager().createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("pLogin", pLogin);
    query.setParameter("pSenha", pSenha);       

    try {
        return (Usuario) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Uma outra maneira é fazer a busca utilizando o método [getResultList](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--), mesmo que o resultado seja vazio, ele não irá lançar uma `exception`, daí você só verifica se a lista retornada é vazia, caso negativo retorna o primeiro item da lista:

```
public Usuario getUsuarioLogin(String pLogin, String pSenha) {       
    String hql = " select u from Usuario u "
               + " where u.login =:pLogin "
               + " and u.senha =:pSenha ";

    Query query = this.getManager().createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("pLogin", pLogin);
    query.setParameter("pSenha", pSenha); 

    List users = query.getResultList();

    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return (Usuario) results.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Costuma ser ruim retornar `null` (o Uncle Bob, no seu livro _Clean Code_, é um que comenta sobre isso), você força um check desnecessário em outro(s) ponto(s) do programa e cria um ponto potencial de bug. Bem melhor seria, no `catch`, retornar simplesmente um `Usuario` vazio.

Comment: Sim, força uma checagem externa, nesse caso em específico, acho que o melhor seria retornar um boolean informando sucesso ou falha, não teria o risco de uma NPE ou verificações em todos os pontos que o código é utilizado